# Irreducible representations of a finite group are equivalent?

Tags: representation-theory

Given a finite group $G$. If $D(g)$ and $D'(g)$ are injective irreducible representations of $G$, do $D(g)$ and $D'(g)$ have to be equivalent? That is $SD(g)S^{-1} = D'(g)$?

We assume here complex irreducibility.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your statement is true. See irreducible representations of simple groups (say $A_5$) as examples: they are all injective if non-trivial.